# how to convert list to RGB value in python

Tags: python, numpy, math, rgb, fibonacci

I'm trying to convert fibonacci series to rgb image. so

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
N = int(input("Number of elements in Fibonacci Series, N, (N>=2) : "))

#starting elements: 0, 1
fibonacciSeries = [0,1]

if N>2:
    for i in range(2, N):
        nextElement = fibonacciSeries[i-1] + fibonacciSeries[i-2]
        fibonacciSeries.append(nextElement)
print(fibonacciSeries)
fib_arr = np.array(fibonacciSeries)
fib_arr
img =np.zeros((100,100,4))

rgb = []
for i in fibonacciSeries:
    rgb.append(i % 255)
print(rgb)
```

all this process ı have a list of mod each index of fib_Arr like that!

```
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 122, 100, 222, 67, 34, 101, 135, 236, 116, 97, 213, 55, 13, 68, 81, 149, 230, 124, 99, 223, 67, 35, 102, 137, 239, 121, 105, 226, 76, 47, 123, 170, 38, 208, 246, 199, 190, 134, 69, 203, 17, 220, 237, 202, 184, 131, 60, 191, 251, 187, 183, 115, 43, 158, 201, 104, 50, 154, 204, 103, 52, 155, 207, 107, 59, 166, 225, 136, 106, 242, 93, 80, 173, 253, 171, 169, 85, 254, 84, 83, 167, 250, 162, 157, 64, 221]
```

now how to convert this value to RGB image

I try to

```
plt.imshow(rgb)
plt.savefig("rgb.png")
```

but doesn't work

edited:

```
rgb_arr = np.array(rgb)
rgb_arr

array([  0,   1,   1,   2,   3,   5,   8,  13,  21,  34,  55,  89, 144,
       233, 122, 100, 222,  67,  34, 101, 135, 236, 116,  97, 213,  55,
        13,  68,  81, 149, 230, 124,  99, 223,  67,  35, 102, 137, 239,
       121, 105, 226,  76,  47, 123, 170,  38, 208, 246, 199, 190, 134,
        69, 203,  17, 220, 237, 202, 184, 131,  60, 191, 251, 187, 183,
       115,  43, 158, 201, 104,  50, 154, 204, 103,  52, 155, 207, 107,
        59, 166, 225, 136, 106, 242,  93,  80, 173, 253, 171, 169,  85,
       254,  84,  83, 167, 250, 162, 157,  64])


from PIL import Image
img = Image.fromarray(rgb_arr, 'RGB')
img.save('test.png')
img.show()
```

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xhyua.jpg)

Comment: How do you want to convert this array to RGB?

Comment: RGB colors have 0-255 values so each pixel has a value of the list. but how I do convert and show the plt graphic?

Comment: ı convert list to np array rgb_arr = np.array(rgb)    rgb_arr array([  0,   1,   1,   2,   3,   5,   8,  13,.... ] maybe ı can convert these way

Comment: There are 100 items, so it cannot be divided by 3 (RGB components)... Otherwise you could use something like `np.array(fibonacciSeries, dtype=np.uint8).reshape((-1, 3))`. Note that `%255` generate values between 0-254 included and not 0-255 included, but I guess you want the second one.

Comment: What doesn't work?  What does happen,and what is wrong?

Comment: I edited, I am trying to draw an image of Fibonacci mod 255 and maybe I find a pattern... I have an array called **rgb_arr** but ı don't know how to convert images I am researching and trying something **picture** but ı added this image with something wrong about dimensions. so how to do the first 100 fib number of mod 255 in a matrix to image?